# Visual Studio 2015 debugging: Symbols cannot be loaded until I restart my computer

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

Recently, whenever I change something in my code, rebuild, and attempt to debug, I get the error "This breakpoint will not currently be hit, No symbols have been loaded for this document."

But then as soon as I restart my computer, everything is fine and I can debug properly. Why is this happening? It's really frustrating having to restart my desktop every time I try to debug my code. I've looked all over stack overflow and MSDN and can't find any solution to my particular problem. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> "This breakpoint will not currently be hit, No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document."

(*As for this error message, it's common error which has different causes. I can't give the most direct correct answer for this issue, I can only give you some tips for trouble-shooting. In order to avoid losing contact in the round-trip comments, I post those content as answer instead of comments.*)

Since VS2015 have been released for long time, I would think this issue is a particular one, not found similar issues online.

First of all, please create a new simple project to check if this issue occurs in new project when debugging.

**If it persists in new project**, I think this issue has something to do outside environment like VS settings, VS config files or Debug options. 
You can try:

1.Go `Tools=>Import and Export Settings=>Reset all settings =>No,just reset settings=>Finish`

2.Repair VS IDE since it seems to work well in the past, and just got the issue recently, so maybe something is broken for your IDE(In Control Panel find VS2015, `right-click=>change=>repair`). Also, make sure you have the latest VS2015 Update3 instead of earlier versions.

**And if it works well in new project**, then maybe the issue is about `the whole project or solution itself`. You can try:

1.Navigate to solution folder, close all vs instance, delete the `.vs, bin and obj` folders and restart VS to check if it helps.

2.Make sure you've loaded the required symbols, check the content in your [Modules window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-modules-window?view=vs-2019#load-symbols) during debugging, there's possibility you don't load necessary symbols successfully.

3.Check the output folder after your rebuild, check in folder like `bin\debug` folder if you have both the `.exe and .pdb` files. And make sure the .exe and .pdb files are `up-to-date` after your rebuild by checking their `Date Modified`.

Hope it helps and more info about the project type, dependencies would be better:)